# JSON web hook to MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, webhooks

I'm a starting with PHP and I have a web server that receives an incoming web hook in JSON format.

The web hook can come in 3 different structures based on the object. Each different format gets inserted in to a different table based on "type":.

The 3 formats for webhook are as follows.

1.

```html
{"message": 
   {"team_id": 3, 
    "place_points": 4000, 
    "last_modified": 1480297989459, 
    "latitude": 27.140134, 
    "guard_object_id": 130, 
    "enabled": true, 
    "place_id": "YjliYjRkYzJiZmI0NDIyZj"placezRlZmM0OGFhOWIxMTguMTY=",      
    "longitude": -80.192017}, 
    "type": "place"}
```

2.

```html
{"message": 
    {"bonus_expiration": null, 
     "store_id": "YjhlMWQ3MDcwN2EzNGMwY2I1NGE5YzVmNDA3ZWRlMGIuMTY=", 
     "enabled": true, "longitude": -80.197377, 
     "last_modified": 1474148043976, 
     "active_fort_modifier": null, 
     "latitude": 27.146217}, 
     "type": "store"}
```

3.

```html
{"message": 
    {"disappear_time": 1480353234, 
    "meeting_id": "88dedc26aad", 
    "move_2": null, 
    "time_until_hidden_ms": 1411382559, 
    "last_modified_time": 1480352334560, 
    "encounter_id": "MzIxNTQ1NzIzMzMzMDExOTI5Mg==", 
    "move_1": null, 
    "individual_defense": null, 
    "object_id": 13, 
    "individual_stamina": null, 
    "time_detail": -1, 
    "longitude": -80.19295513708012, 
    "latitude": 27.141183040207377, 
    "individual_attack": null}, 
    "type": "object"}
```

This is PHP I've put together, but its not working when im sending the webhook to the address of the PHP Script. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```html
<?php


# MySQL database connection info
$host = 'localhost:3306';
$dbname = 'xxxxxxx';
$user = 'xxxxxxx';
$password = '-------';
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $user, $password);

# Define Type Variables

$place = 'place';
$store = 'store';
$object = 'object';

# Decide if the WebHook is a place, store, or object

//$input = file_get_contents('mysql_webhook_payload.json'); # Local file for debugging
$input = file_get_contents('php://input'); # POST data from webhook
$payload = json_decode($input, true);

#IF LOOP for type

if ($payload['message']['type'] == $place ) {

  $team_id = $payload['message']['team_id'];
  $place_points = $payload['message']['place_points'];
  $last_modified = $payload['message']['last_modified'];
  $latitude = $payload['message']['latitude'];
  $guard_object_id = $payload['message']['guard_object_id'];      
  $enabled = $payload['message']['enabled']; 
  $place_id = $payload['message']['place_id'];      
  $longitude = $payload['message']['longitude'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO places (`place_id`, `team_id`, `guard_object_id`, `place_points`, `enabled`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `last_modified`) 
            VALUE ($place_id, $team_id, $guard_object_id, $place_points, $enabled, $latitude, $longitude, $last_modified)";  
}
else if ($payload['message']['type'] == $store ) {
    $bonus_expiration = $payload['message']['bonus_expiration'];
    $store_id = $payload['message']['store_id'];
    $enabled = $payload['message']['enabled'];
    $longitude = $payload['message']['longitude'];
    $last_modified = $payload['message']['last_modified'];
    $active_fort_modifier = $payload['message']['bonus_expiration'];
    $latitude = $payload['message']['latitude'];

    ////missing sql entry


}
else if ($payload['message']['type'] == $object ) {
    $disappear_time = $payload['message']['disappear_time'];
    $meeting_id = $payload['message']['meeting_id'];
    $encounter_id = $payload['message']['encounter_id'];
    $longitude = $payload['message']['longitude'];
    $last_modified_time = $payload['message']['last_modified_time'];
    $move_1 = $payload['message']['move_1'];
    $latitude = $payload['message']['latitude'];
    $individual_defense = $payload['message']['individual_defense'];
    $object_id = $payload['message']['object_id'];
    $individual_stamina = $payload['message']['individual_stamina'];
    $individual_attack = $payload['message']['individual_attack'];
    $time_detail = $payload['message']['time_detail'];
    $move_2 = $payload['message']['move_2'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `object`(`encounter_id`, `meeting_id`, `object_id`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `disappear_time`, `individual_attack`, `individual_defense`, `individual_stamina`, `move_1`, `move_2`, `last_modified`, `time_detail`) VALUES ($encounter_id, $meeting_id, $object_id, $latitude, $longitude, $disappear_time, $individual_attack, $individual_defense, $individual_stamina, $move_1, $move_2, $last_modified, $time_detail)";

}

?>
```

I am probably way off here

Comment: I fail to understand why you are not inserting the data directly with python. If your python script is running on a different computer, it's irrelevent to this discussion. You have made the question quite unclear and confusing by mentioning it. Last but not least how can you expect the database to be populated without actually executing any sql on it?

Comment: My goal, which I should have stated is having multiple people running the python application locally and contributing data. The python code isn't mine, nor do I know python. the code has built in ability to send a JSON web hook to a variable address, and that is how I will be collecting contributions. inside my "if" is an sql entry.

Comment: so edit your question. Please remove that 'run code snippet stuff' that's not runnable code you have posted.

Comment: Leave out the python stuff, say you have a webserver that recieves the json that you have posted. And you have having trouble inserting it into the database with php. That really is all that's relevent here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet is invalid as it contains quote `"` in the `place_id` string.

It's not `$payload['message']['type']` but `$payoload['type']`. Note `},` before `type` key.

When you solve above you will probably get SQL error as your inserts are not escaped nor quoted. You should use [PDO's bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

The rest of the code should be fine, works for me.

Comment: The invalid string was me Find/replace code. Thank you very much for your help, this solved my question

Comment: Sorry, first asking on stack overflow! Thank you again!